# Masking dataframe by substring in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe called tags

```
abc
123489
abcdefg
qwerabcas
sid abc 239
8273491
```

Please give me a way for me to be able to display the rows where abc is present so the output will have rows

```
abc
abcdefg
qwerabcas
sid abc 239
```

Comment: Try ```df.loc[df.tags.str.contains('abc'), :]```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df[df['tags'].str.contains('abc')]
```

Comment: **ALT 1**: `df[['abc' in x for x in df.tags]]`

Comment: **ALT 2**: `df.query('tags.str.contains("abc")')`